# Laravel - data showed not based on 'where' statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**My Tables:**

> **Employee**
>
> id | name
>
> **Overtime**
>
> id | total_day | date
>
> **Overtime_Details**
>
> id | overtime_id | employee_id | payment

**My Controller:**

```
public function details($id,$day)
    {
        $day        = $d; // d -> day on buttons
        $count      = DB::table('overtime')
                    ->select ('employee.name as employeename', 'overtime_details.payment as paymentemployee')
                    ->join ('overtime_details', 'overtime_details.overtime_id', '=', 'overtime.id')
                    ->join ('employee', 'employee.id', '=', 'overtime_details.employee_id')
                    ->where ('day', $d)
                    ->get();
        // dd($count);

        return view('countovertime.overtimedetails')->withCount($count);
    }
```

When I use the `dd`,  `$count` function to check the data obtained it worked properly as I expected, but when the `dd` data check function is turned off and back to the view page to select the first day button the page displayed for the first day employee overtime, but when clicked the button for the second day the page still showed the first day's data.

**Here's my page view:**

[ Button day 1 ] [ Button day 2 ] ->this based on the table in overtime "**day**"

**My Button Controller:**

```
return DataTables::eloquent($model)
        ->addColumn('day', function(countovertime $st){
$links = '';
        for ($d = 1; $h <= $st->day; $d++) {

        $links .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="overtimedetails/'. $st->id .'/'.$d.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Day-'. $d .'</a>';
            }
            return $links;
```

Comment: `$d` is not defined in function and not even passed. Isn't that showing any error?

Comment: No errors, it worked but the page always showed the first day eventhough the button links showed the second day.

Comment: I guessed the `Day` should be taking from the tables right?because I only do increement function for the button sums.

Comment: As mentioned, `$d` is not set, so no matter what `$day` you pass the same query is executed.  It isn't clear what the point of the `$day = $d` variable juggling is ... your method gets `$day`, can you not just use it?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function, change `$day = $d` to `$d = $day;`

Answer (score 0):

You declare $day = $d; // d -> day on buttons

Here change the value as

$d = $day;